# Python - считывание с приложения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть какое-то приложение, в котором есть своя консоль (открывается по нажатию кнопки), где пишутся действия пользователя. Например, он выбрал какой-то пункт меню - сразу об этом сообщается в консоли отдельной строкой. И есть приложение, написанное на Python, которое нужно научить считывать записи из этой консоли в режиме реального времени. Я не так давно в программировании, поэтому прошу у вас помощи - мои поиски в гугле особых результатов не дали, так как я даже не знаю принцип работы и название всего этого процесса. Нужны какие-либо статьи/книги/etc., где рассказывается доступным языком о подобных вещах на языке Python, можно на английском. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
with Popen('cmd', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE) as bat:
    bat.stdin.write('ping 127.0.0.1\n'.encode())
    bat.stdin.close()
    for o in bat.stdout:
        print(o.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
        print('my_string')
```

OUT:

```
C:\Python344\python.exe E:/python/2016/2/2222.py
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
my_string
(c) ௮  (Microsoft Corporation), 2013.  ࠢ 饭.
my_string
my_string
E:\python\2016\2>ping 127.0.0.1
my_string
my_string
 ⠬  127.0.0.1   32 ⠬ :
my_string
⢥  127.0.0.1: ᫮ =32 ६<1 TTL=128
my_string
⢥  127.0.0.1: ᫮ =32 ६<1 TTL=128
        ...
E:\python\2016\2>
my_string
```

видимо надо чтото типа этого и почитать о subprocess

Comment: У автора похоже GUI программа, которая печатает в своё окошко, а не консоль (нет стандартных потоков). Related: [Interact with other programs using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14288177/4279). Если консольная программа, которая использует stdin, stdout, stderr, то верно в сторону `subprocess`, `pexpect` модулей надо смотреть.

Comment: @jfs Так точно, GUI программа. Вроде бы всё более менее понятно, спасибо за ссылку, но возник такой вопрос (возможно, глупый): если программа будет написана с использованием pywin32, то будет ли работать считывание с того же самого приложения, если программу и приложение запустить на другой ОС, то есть не на Windows?

Comment: @NickCaulfield ответ: нет, да, это зависит. Вы лучше вопрос обновите или новый задайте, где подробно описано *что* вы хотите получить, а только потом описывайте неудачные попытки решения (pywin32). Если вам нужна переносимая программа, то пытаться соскрести текст, рисуемый на экран некой неуказанной GUI программкой, не самый лучший вариант (лучший вариант зависит, что это за программка: можно ли найти библиотеки, консольные варианты по аналогии с [этим ответом](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14338006/4279))